# Can't read the same InputStream twice

Tags: java, inputstream, apache-tika, boilerpipe

This is my code:

```
// getFile() method returns the input stream of a local or online file
InputStream fileStream = getFile(source);
// Convert an InputStream to an InputSource
org.xml.sax.InputSource fileSource = new org.xml.sax.InputSource(fileStream);
// Extract text via the Boilerpipe DefaultExtractor
String text = DefaultExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(fileSource);

// Extract text and metadata via Apache Tika
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
parser.parse(fileStream, handler, metadata, context);
```

I can't figure out why just the first extractor works.

In this case just **Boilerpipe** (the first extractor) works, while **Apache Tika** (the second extractor) is not able to extract anything.

I tried to create a copy of `fileStream` (via `InputStream fileStream2 = fileStream;`) and to pass `fileStream` to one reader and `fileStream2` to another reader, but it didn't work either.

I also tried passing to Boilerpipe the HTML extracted from `fileStream`, and `fileStream` to Tika, but the result was the same.

I suspect that the problem is that the same `InputStream` cannot be read twice.

Could you please help me how to pass the content of 1 `InputStream` to 2 readers?

**EDIT:**
I found the solution and I posted it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that an `InputStream` can't be read twice as Tika and Boilerpipe did in my old code, so I figured out that I could read `fileStream` and convert it to `String`, pass it to Boilerpipe, convert the `String` to a `ByteArrayInputStream` and pass that to Tika.
This is my new code.

```
// getFile() method returns the input stream of a local or online file
InputStream fileStream = getFile(source);

// Read the value of the InputStream and pass it to the
// Boilerpipe DefaultExtractor in order to extract the text
String html = readFromStream(fileStream);
String text = DefaultExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(html);

// Convert the value read from fileStream to a new ByteArrayInputStream
fileStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes("UTF-8"));

// Extract text and metadata via Apache Tika
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
parser.parse(fileStream, handler, metadata, context);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a maven project, you have to include these dependencies (in your `pom.xml`) in order that **`boilerpipe`** could work:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>x.y.z</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
        <version>x.y.z</version>
</dependency>
```